# What is the 'Direct reference'?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a question about the 'direct reference'. Following is an advice of my advising professor.

> "you can use direct references to all definitions and theorems since Latex allows it. Then you do not need to care about numbering and you can concentrate on writing the contents and vary the order / add / delete etc these items without causing any extra trouble."

From this context, what is the direct reference? I couldn't find any information about it. Please let me know some similar function of LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I suppose your professor was trying to say that you should use LaTeX's built-in `\label`-`\ref` machinery to generate cross-references to numbered items such as theorems, definitions, equations, figures, tables, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing has a nice write up.